# What are reasons for Karna's death?

Tags: mahabharata, death, sin

It is said that there are 10s of reasons as a consequence of which [Karna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karna) met his death, what are they?

How is he eligible for heaven and liberty, as quoted [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karna#Ascension_to_svarga)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many reasons For karna's death,as given in Wikipedia

- Parashurama laid curse upon Karna that he would forget all the knowledge required to wield the divine weapon Brahmanda astra, at the moment of his greatest need.
- Karna was also cursed by a Brahmin for killing his cow while practising his skills with bow and arrows.
- BhoomiDevi cursed him that at a very crucial moment in battle, his chariot wheel would be trapped tightly in the mud
- Kunti extracted a boon from him that he would not kill anyone of her sons except Arjuna
- Kunti asked him not to use the nagastra more than once
- His charioteer Salya deserted him at an important moment
- Indra took away karna's *Kavacha Kundala*(natural armour)
- He exhausted the Vajrayudha he had reserved to kill Arjuna on Ghatotkatcha(Bheema's son)

Karna attained Svarga(heaven) not *Moksha*(liberty) ,as all *Kshatriyas*(warriors) who die in war are sure to attain heaven.

Lord Krishna says in the Gita that war is like an open door to heaven for a kshatriya
Here is the sloka fore reference:

> Yaddrchaya choppapannam svarga dvaaram apavrutam
>   Sukhinaya Kshatriya Partha labhante yuddham idrsam

Answer (score 1):

Narada narrates the story of Karna to Yudhisthira after war when the dead people in the battlefield are cremated and ashes scattered in Ganga and tells how and why Arjuna was able to slay Karna.

> In consequence of a Brahmana's curse, as also of the curse of the illustrious Rama, of the boon granted to Kunti and the illusion practised on him by Indra, of his depreciation by Bhishma as only half a car-warrior, at the tale of Rathas and Atirathas, of the destruction of his energy caused by Salya (with his keen speeches), of Vasudeva's policy, and, lastly of the celestial weapons obtained by Arjuna from Rudra and Indra and Yama and Varuna and Kuvera and Drona and the illustrious Kripa, the wielder of Gandiva succeeded in slaying Vikartana's son Karna of effulgence like that of Surya himself.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a005.htm

Answer (score 0):

The main reasons were

1. Karna insulted Sati Draupadi by calling her prostitute in Vastraharana.
2. Karna supported Duryodhana and unrighteousness.

That is the main reason for his death.

He attained paradise, because Indra was bound to take every person to paradise who will die in Mahabharata's [Kurukhestra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurukshetra) war land.

> The **Vamana Purana** tells how King Kuru came to settle on this land. He chose this land at the banks of Sarasvati River(since dried up before 1900BCE[3]) for embedding spirituality with 8 virtues: austerity (tapas), truth (satya), forgiveness (kshama), kindness (daya), purity (suchee[disambiguation needed]), charity (daan), yagya and brahmacharya. Lord Vishnu was impressed with the act of King Kuru and blessed him. God gave him two boons, one that this land forever will be known as a Holy Land after his name as Kurukshetra (the land of Kuru) and the other that anyone dying on this land will be going to heaven.

Nobody has gone to paradise to see he attained paradise or not, it is written in Mahabharata so we believe he may attained paradise. **The point is he was on bad side. And his karma led him to death.**